# Bundle envoy proxy with executable and ship it to end user machine

Tags: c++, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I am creating a C++ gRPC server and clients will be gRPC-web based.
As per the documentation this setup will require Envoy Proxy in between to convert HTTP 1.1 requests to HTTP2 and send it to gRPC server.

`C++ gRPC server  <->  Envoy Proxy <--> Web gRPC client`

On development machine, I can run the proxy using `envoy --config-path  proxy.ymal`

My question is, how can i bundle the envoy pre-built binaries along with C++ gRPC server?

So that when user double click and runs the C++ gRPC server, the envoy proxy start running along with it?